# ng-min based on condition Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

just started to develop with angularjs,
googled for a while by now, but with no success, i guess what i am doing is not the right way, and it is not working.
could some one help me to set conditional ng-min, so both year and month fields cannot be 0 at one time, but one of them could be.Thank you all

```
<md-input-container>
                    <label>Years</label>
                    <input ng-model="employer.years" type="number" ng-min="0" ng-max="50" ng-change="calculateMonth()" ng-required="employer.month == '0'" name="years">
                    <div ng-messages="employerForm.years.$error" role="alert" multiple>
                        <div ng-message="max" class="my-message">Max allowed value is 50
                        </div>
                        <div ng-message="min" class="my-message">Please enter a valid number from 0 to 50
                        </div>
                        <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">This field is required
                        </div>
                        <div  class="my-message"><p ng-bind="msg"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
            </div>
  <div layout="row">
                <md-input-container>
                    <label>Months</label>
                    <input ng-model="employer.month" type="number"   ng-min="0" ng-max="11" ng-required="employer.years == '0'" name="month">
                    <div ng-messages="employerForm.month.$error" role="alert" multiple>
                        <div ng-message="max" class="my-message">Max allowed value is 11, you can always add a year
                        </div>
                        <div ng-message="min" class="my-message">Please enter a valid number from 0 to 11
                        </div>
                        <div ng-message="required" class="my-message">This field is required
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </md-input-container>
```

Controller code

```
 $scope.calculateMonth = function () {
            if($scope.employer.years){
                    $scope.employer.month = 0;
                    if($scope.employer.month === 0 && $scope.employer.years === 0){
                        console.log('both are zero');
                        $scope.msg = 'Both values can not be 0'
                    }
                    $scope.msg = "Something Entered";
        }};
```

Comment: What do you want to have happen if both fields are 0? What are their defaults?

Comment: When both are 0 just to present a message asking to correct one of them.